# Accessing nested object properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an object which comes from `FieldErrors` react-hook-form, however, I am not sure how to access the object in order to retrieve the `message` property. The object shown in the image below comes from react-hook `FieldErrors` where I added the following console statement:

```
console.log('this1: ', errorProps)
```

[image]

I am not sure how to access this `errorProps` message property. `FieldErrors` has `message, type, root, ref` and `types` associated with it however all of them return back undefined for example, `console.log('this1: ', errorProps?.message)` returns back undefined. How can I access the message property shown in the image?

---

```
<Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" >
  {Object.entries(errors).map(([fieldId, errorProps]) => (
    <Box display="flex" >
      {console.log('this1: ', errorProps)}
      <Typography type="negative">{`${errorProps?.message || errorProps?.root?.message}`}</Typography>
    </Box>
  ))}
</Box>
```

Comment: You're looking at an *array* of objects with properties with objects. `errorProps` doesn't have `message` directly! More something like `errorProps[0]['M13814-M14170'].message`! You're probably supposed to iterate over the array and the properties within the object.

Comment: @deceze I am still unable to access it via bracket notation you showed. I have updated my question to include the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```
[] implies array
{} implies object
0: is the index of the object in the array
you have it opened, so you see the values which is also an object
M13814-m14170 is a key
: { type: required, message... } is the final object you want.

errorProps[0]['M13814-M14170']['message'] is the value you want.

[0,1,2] indexes of an array
[{},{},{}] 3 objects at index 0, 1 & 2.

Your example has only one object.
[{}]

And within that object you have this:
[{ "M13814-M14170": { type: 'required', message: '... }]
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried your suggestion but I get a syntax error. I have updated my question to include the code snippet.

Comment: This is assuming of course the part M13814-M14170 doesn't update.

Comment: Otherwise if it's not static you'll have to do a little more:
const [ key ] = Object.keys(errorProps[0]);
console.log(errorProps[0][key].message);

Comment: I used lodash `get(errorProps, '0.M13814-M14170.message')` and that worked for me however manual using bracket notation gives me syntax error. Not sure why this is.

Answer (score 1):

As @deceze already mentioned in his comment: in order to extract the error message from each of the error-objects you might find in your `errorProps` array you could do the following:

```js
const errorProps=[{"M13814-M14170": { type: "required", message: "this is the error message" }},
                  {"M15773-M00815": { type: "optional", message: "yet another error message" }}];

const msg=errorProps.map(err=>{
  let [[k,v]]=Object.entries(err);
  return `${k}: ${v.message}`; }).join("\n");
console.log(msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided code snippet appears to be written in JSX, likely within a React component. It iterates through the entries of an `errors` object, presumably containing error information related to form fields. For each entry, it attempts to render an error message using the `Typography` component. However, there is a potential issue with using `console.log` within JSX, as JSX is primarily intended for rendering components.

```
<Box display="flex" flexDirection="column">
  {Object.entries(errors).map(([fieldId, errorProps]) => (
    <Box key={fieldId} display="flex" flexDirection="column"> {/* Add a unique "key" prop */}
      <Typography variant="body1" color="error">
        {errorProps?.message || (errorProps?.root && errorProps.root.message)}
      </Typography>
    </Box>
  ))}
</Box>
```

Comment: I only added the console.log to see what was returning in errorProps message since it was giving me undefined in my UI.